# "Select All" option for XPages valuePicker Control?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to use the valuePicker XPages Extension Library control. I realize that you can hold down the Control button to select multiple values at a time, but is there a way to add the ability to select all values/options? Thanks for any help.

```
<xp:inputText id="example" multipleSeparator=","></xp:inputText>
<xe:valuePicker for="example" pickerText="Choose option">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker
            valueList="Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4, Option 5"
            valueListSeparator=",">
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

Comment: Code to generate that dialog is hard coded inside ExtLib plugin. That means you can extend it and generate your own functions/look. Easier approach could be (not sure it will work) to use Dojo to alter generated HTML and add hotspot with some JS to select all elements. That way you wouldn't need to distribute plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will give those things a try.